# How can I adjust row height/column width with either a table style or cell style? - InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, tables, cell

Is there a way to adjust the column width or row height within either a cell style or a table style?

When I open the cell style options window there is no side tab for adjusting row/height.
[image]

with the the table style options there doesn't seem to be any option either
[image]

What I am trying to do is basically I have some headers set up for a drinks menu and I want to adjust their height because the menu doesn't fit on the page. But I want an easy way like a style that I could just adjust the height which would affect all the table cells that style is applied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hoping for a *yes*, but its a *no*.

Table and cell styles don't address specific widths and heights, you need to do that manually. As you've probably noticed already, the styles are more about fills, strokes and padding.

When adjusting row heights manually, you can select a range of rows or the entire table, to quickly apply a specific height. If you have breaker rows, like headers, etc, you can copy paste the entire row in another location and it will replicate the height settings, strokes, fonts, everything.